# How to allow user to keep scrolling until last item of list is in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this lazy row with items that the user can scroll through but when I scroll to the end of the list I cannot keep scrolling so the last item stays on the right side of the screen when I need it to be right in the middle (there's an effect there so I want all items to have it). How can I achieve this with compose?

```
 LazyRow(
                    state = listState,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(data) { i, _ ->
                        val opacity by remember {
                            derivedStateOf {
                                val currentItemInfo = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                                    .firstOrNull { it.index == i }
                                    ?: return@derivedStateOf 1f
                                 (1f - minOf(
                                    1f,
                                    abs(currentItemInfo.offset - halfRowWidth).toFloat() )
                               }
                        }

                        
                    }

                }
```

Comment: If all your elements have the same fixed width, you can just put an empty box as the last item in the LazyRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple thing to do is just to add a spacer inside the item block at the end of your Lazy list. The width of the spacer can be half of the parent width since you want it the last item in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```kotlin
BoxWithConstraints {
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            top = 8.dp,
            end = maxWidth / 2, // maxWidth from BoxWithConstraintsScope
            bottom = 8.dp,
        ),
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(cardData) { i, _ -> /**/ }
    }
}
```

This will indent the end of the list so it can be scrolled further. The code snippet does not take into account the width of the element, so at the maximum scroll right edge of the last element will be in the center of the list. If you want it to stop strictly in the center, you need to take it into account of end padding:

```kotlin
PaddingValues(
    top = 8.dp,
    end = maxWidth / 2 - listElementWidth / 2,
    bottom = 8.dp,
)
```